# получить значения элементов через js

Tags: javascript

Есть табличная верстка, в каждой строке по 2 столбца, т.е. структура такая:

```
<tr>
  <td>1 столбец</td>
  <td>2 столбец</td>
</tr>
```

Выбираю все строки из таблицы:

```
var rows = window.document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");
```

Мне нужно получить значение обоих столбцов. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```js
var rows = window.document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr");

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { // перебираем все строки
  var cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td'); // получаем столбцы
  for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) { // перебираем все столбцы
    console.log(cols[j].textContent); // выводим текст из столбца
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1 столбец</td>
      <td>2 столбец</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам вернется набор всех подходящих элементов. В итоге вам нужно просто по всем им пройтись. Это можно сделать следующим образом: использовать метод `arr.forEach(callback[, thisArg])` для перебора массива.

Он для каждого элемента массива вызывает функцию `callback`.

Этой функции он передаёт три параметра `callback(item, i, arr)`:

`item` – очередной элемент массива.
`i` – его номер.
`arr` – массив, который перебирается.
Например:

`var arr = ["Яблоко", "Апельсин", "Груша"];`

```
arr.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
  alert( i + ": " + item + " (массив:" + arr + ")" );
});
```

Второй, необязательный аргумент `forEach` позволяет указать контекст `this` для `callback`.

Метод `forEach` ничего не возвращает, его используют только для перебора, как более «элегантный» вариант, чем обычный цикл `for`.

```js
var rows = window.document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td");

rows.forEach(function(item){
  alert(item.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1 столбец</td>
    <td>2 столбец</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` возвращает не массив

Comment: @Grundy, вы не прав, ...SelectorAll возвращает коллекцию элементов, которая является псевдомассмовом, сольвент логичнее назвать возвращаемое значение массивом, нежели как-то иначе.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, Нет не логичнее, так как, у этой коллекции отсутствуют методы массива. Опять же название _псевдо_-массив, как бы намекает, что возвращаемое значение **не является** массивом

Answer (score 1):

1. Получим все ряды таблицы.
2. Сделаем из нод-листа массив нод (`[...rows]`). Так у нас появится массив строчек таблицы.
3. По каждой строчке таблицы пройдемся `Array#map`, получим из нее массив ячеек (`item => [...item.cells]`).
4. Получим содержимое ячеек в этом же цикле, пройдясь еще раз по нему (`[...item.cells].map(item => item.innerHTML)`).

На выходе получится массив массивов с содержимым ячеек.

```js
let rows = document.querySelector('table').rows;

let cells = [...rows].map(item => [...item.cells].map(item => item.innerHTML));

console.log(cells);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1 столбец</td>
    <td>2 столбец</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1-1 столбец</td>
    <td>2-1 столбец</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1-2 столбец</td>
    <td>2-2 столбец</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```